# pagination crashes my appl

Tags: javafx, pagination

I've got this database with 15 items which I load in a tableview and have set the number of rows on 10. It loads the first 10 (on page1), and with the use of pagination it loads the last 5 (on page2). However when I move forward with pagination, it crashes. Obviously there are no more rows with items to show but still, how can I fix this?

```
public class ProductListController implements Initializable {

@FXML private Pagination page;


    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

        assert tableview !=null : " "; 

         ProductName.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().productNameProperty());
         ProductPrice.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().productPriceProperty());
         Stock.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().productStockProperty());
         Supplier.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().productSupplierProperty());
         Contact.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().productContactProperty());
         buildData();        
    }

        private ObservableList<MyTable> data;

    private Node createPage(int pageIndex) {
    int rowsPerPage = 10;
    int fromIndex = pageIndex * rowsPerPage;
    int toIndex = Math.min(fromIndex + rowsPerPage, data.size());
    tableview.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(data.subList(fromIndex, toIndex)));

    return (tableview);
}

   public void buildData(){
    data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

          try{
        MyConnection mc = new MyConnection ();
        ResultSet rs; 
        rs = mc.getConnection();


    while (rs.next()) {
     MyTable mod = new MyTable();


     mod.productName.set(rs.getString("NAME"));
     mod.productPrice.set(rs.getString("SELL_PRICE"));
     mod.productStock.set(rs.getInt("STOCK"));
     mod.productSupplier.set(rs.getString("SUPPLIER"));
     mod.productContact.set(rs.getString("CONTACT"));

     data.add(mod);

     page.setPageFactory(this::createPage);
         }

      }

    catch ( SQLException | IOException err) {
    System.out.println(err.getMessage() ); 
    }


    }
}
```

Comment: Crashes? Or throws an exception? If it throws an exception, post the stack trace.

Comment: An exception: Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: fromIndex(20) > toIndex(15)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the page count on the pagination, to limit the number of pages available.

Move the `rowsPerPage` to a field (instead of a local variable) and then after loading the data do

```
public void initialize() {
    // ...
    buildData();
    int pageCount = data.size() / rowsPerPage ;
    if (pageCount * rowsPerPage < data.size()) {
        pageCount = pageCount + 1 ;
    }
    page.setPageCount(pageCount);
}
```

Comment: Aha, thank you once again. So, is this always the case? If you have more pages than needed it gives an exception? Because there is nothing left to show.

Comment: No, it gives the exception in this case because of the reason stated in the stack trace: you call `subList` with the `fromIndex` being less than the `toIndex`. But you do that because your computations of those values assume you are on a valid page. Of course, if you have a limited number of pages, it is a better user experience to limit the number of choices in the pagination anyway.

Comment: Ok, so because of the pagecount I've now limited the number of valid pages. Cool, thanks.